# How to create custom CRS with custom SRID in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, srid

In our app we are using several CRS - one of them is a custom one. I'd like to turn it into a proper CRS that PostGIS can fully support (e.g. administering valid transformations on it with something like `ST_Transform`, etc)

How would one do that?

I couldn't find any reference on this online. I found one for Oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/creating-user-defined-coordinate-reference-system.htm#SPATL1455) - seems to be very detailed, transparent and straightforward process. What would be an alternative of this process in case of PostGIS?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239807/create-custom-coordinate-system-in-postgis?rq=1

Comment: @ziggy from what I see answers in that thread are about adding coordinate system that is missing from `spatial_ref_sys` table, but is already defined somewhere else (on https://www.spatialreference.org/ perhaps?). That's not what I'm looking for. I have totally made up coordinate system and want to properly add it to `spatial_ref_sys`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a row to the [`spatial_ref_sys` table](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#spatial_ref_sys).

The most important column is `proj4text`, which describes the projection for the [PROJ library](https://proj.org/operations/index.html). (Despite the name, the latest PostGIS uses the latest version of PROJ.)

I do not know if the `srtext` value is actually necessary, but you should be able to create it with [gdalsrsinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalsrsinfo.html).

<sup>Also see [Managing custom projections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/316252/10588) and [Would it be worthwhile to use the PostGIS extension for custom planets?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/264330/11397)</sup>

Comment: What about `srtext`? Is it derived from `proj4text`?

Comment: It should be possible to derive it from the PROJ string, but I think PROJ has more features than what is defined in the WKT specification.

Comment: I was wondering if specifying both is required, or having `proj4text` would be enough?

Comment: PostGIS itself uses the PROJ string.

Comment: Stumbled upon this quote: `The use of PROJ strings to describe a CRS is considered as legacy (one of the main weakness of PROJ strings is their inability to describe a geodetic datum, other than the few ones hardcoded in the +datum parameter)`, here: https://proj.org/development/quickstart.html

So maybe srtext is actually preferrable.

Comment: PostGIS uses the PROJ library, which uses the PROJ string.